# The complementaries of homologous objects in $S^n$ are homologous?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two subsets of the $n$-sphere $S^n$ that have isomorphic finitely-generated homology groups. Do $S^n\setminus A$ and $S^n\setminus B$ also have isomorphic homology groups?

I can prove it is true if $A$ and $B$ satisfy the [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) assumptions (compact and locally contractible). But I don't know the answer if at least one object does not satisfy these assumptions. Any idea?

Comment: You should use Chech cohomology for compacts $A, B$. Then everything works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. As an example take the [Warsaw circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=warsaw+circle) (aka quasi-circle) $W \subset \mathbb R^2$. It has the same homology groups as a one-point space $P$. We can regard both $W$ and $P$ as subsets of the one-point compactification $S^2$ of $\mathbb R^2$. Clearly $S^2 \setminus P$ is homeomorphic to an open disk. But $S^2 \setminus W$ is homeomorphic to the disjoint union of two open disks( actually we do not need this fact, it suffices to see that $S^2 \setminus W$ has two path components). This shows that $H_0(S^2 \setminus W)$ and  $H_0(S^2 \setminus P)$ are not isomorphic.